# Java: How to send push notifications to a list of URLs?

Tags: java, websocket, push-notification, server-sent-events, java-websocket

**Client Side**

The client sends a POST call to the server to create a subscription.

The POST call request body contains the URL to which the server should send push notifications.

E.g. POST Request body:

```
{ 
    "id": "some ID", 
    "urlToPushNotificationTo": "mysite.com/notifications/not1"
}
```

**Server Side**

The *urlToPushNotificationTo* value is stored in the database.

Then the server will send a push notification to all the URLs stored in the database (whenever an update occurs on the server).

The technologies I'm working on are Java and JBoss server.

I've read about WebSockets and Server-sent Events (SSE) but not sure if it's applicable since I'm creating a list of URLs to push notifications to (and not keeping an active session open).

There's also a limitation to SSE regarding the max amount of open sessions (my application should have no limit).

I've looked at the WebSocket example below. Is it possible to tweak WebSocket to achieve this functionality?

https://github.com/matruskan/websocket-example

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking at a [webhook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook) pattern.

With that, try sending a GET or POST request to the URL from the database.
When it comes to POST, think of the payload you want to transmit.

Comment: I think a webhook will work. I'm also looking into HttpPost (from Apache HttpClients - https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html) and weighing the benefits.